# iOS - call block of code inside same method

Tags: ios, xcode, calendar

I use this code to access the iOS calendar, it works but I realized I have duplicated the code that creates the event; 
first when my phone ask for permission and its granted in iOS 6 or higher
,second when it run in iOS 4 or 5

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        // the selector is available, so we must be on iOS 6 or newer
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (error)
    {
     // display error message here
    }
                else if (!granted)
                {
                    // display access denied error message here
                }
                else
                {
                    // access granted
                    // ***** do the important stuff here *****
                    // i need run my code blow here
                }
            });
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        // this code runs in iOS 4 or iOS 5
        // ***** do the important stuff here *****
       // i need run my code blow here 
    }
```

i would like to call a block of code here to add an event without duplicating the code.

thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not abstract the import code into a separate method rather than having it all be inline? You always want to keep your methods simple and concise.

So where you say;

```
// access granted
// ***** do the important stuff here *****
// i need run my code blow here
[self doSomeImportantStuff];
```

and obviously all your important code belongs in a method:

```
- (void)doSomeImportantStuff {
    // ***** do the important stuff here *****
}
```

Alternatively, if you are committed to having an inline block to perform your work:

```
void (^importBlock)() = ^{
    // ***** do the important stuff here *****
};
```

and later on you can execute this block by simply calling it:

```
importBlock();
```

**EDIT**

for more help on writing blocks take a look at [goshdarnblocksyntax](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com)

Comment: because i pass some data to my main method

Comment: @minafawzy so add that data as a parameter?

Comment: ok i will , but i also want if that possible or not , may be ^ can do that

Comment: @minafawzy that will also work but if you want to write easy to change code you should aspire to abstraction:)

Comment: @minafawzy I updated my post to include a solution using a block, or as you call it ^